# Loading SVG with TextureLoader for three.js canvas results in lower quality than loading via html

Tags: three.js

Loading the SVG with the following code results in a lower quality output than just loading the SVG through html. I get the same result when loading the resource as a PNG instead.  Are there settings, or anything else, that I'm missing here?

```
    // instantiate a loader
    var loader = new THREE.TextureLoader();
            // load a resource
    loader.load(
        // resource URL
        'images/image.svg',
        // Function when resource is loaded
        function ( texture ) {
          // do something with the texture
          var GlobeLogoMaterial = new THREE.MeshBasicMaterial( {
            color:"#ffffff",
            map:texture,
            transparent: true,
                            opacity:1} );
          texture.magFilter = THREE.LinearFilter;
          texture.minFilter = THREE.LinearMipMapLinearFilter;
          var GlobeLogoGeo = new THREE.PlaneGeometry(28,28,1,1);
          var GlobeLogoMesh = new THREE.Mesh( GlobeLogoGeo, GlobeLogoMaterial );
          GlobeLogoMesh.name="Globe Logo Mesh";
          GlobeLogoMesh.position.x = 0;
          GlobeLogoMesh.position.y = 0;
          GlobeLogoMesh.position.z = 31;
          scene.add( GlobeLogoMesh );
        },
        // Function called when download progresses
        function ( xhr ) {
          console.log( (xhr.loaded / xhr.total * 100) + '% loaded' );
        },
        // Function called when download errors
        function ( xhr ) {
          console.log( 'An error happened' );
        }
    );
```

Answer (score 0):

You are loading a vector image (SVG) as a raster texture. Before the vector image is added to the ThreeJS scene it is converted to a raster image. I think you are better off serving your textures as raster images (PNG) so you are in better control of the resolution yourself.

Comment: Thanks for the advice, I have switched to a PNG, but am still losing quality as compared to just loading the image in html. is it possible to maintain the same quality when mapping to a texture?

Comment: In my case, I don't have the option of only serving images as PNG. Is there a way to load an SVG into the scene as a raster texture at a specified target resolution?