# Loading SVG image on threejs getting blurred

Tags: javascript, three.js

I am using loadTexture (THREE.ImageUtils.loadTexture('/images/areaYellow.svg')) for loading svg images 
 but when i zoom in image is getting blurred is there any way to load the image without blur. i am using version 73 . svgloader is started supporting from version 83. i need solution for version 73 or less.

Thanks for reading.

Comment: Related: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42634332/loading-svg-with-textureloader-for-three-js-canvas-results-in-lower-quality-than

Comment: changed to png still same problem

Comment: Possibly it means that you have to convert your svg into png with high resolution.

Comment: Yes its working Thanks

Answer (score -1):

Try setting the width and the height of the SVG, Chrome will render it sharply.

For Example:

```
<svg id="Layer_1" data-name="Layer 1" 
    xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" width="2048" height="1024" viewBox="-2 -40 2048 1024">
```